# How can I tell when Files is done searching?

Tags: nautilus, search, usability

When I search for files in Files, it can take anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes for files to stop being added to the search results. Sometimes I think the search is done, but then more files show up after I've given up waiting.

How can I know for certain when the search is complete, so I know I haven't missed anything?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698906). A fix has not been released at this time.

Answer (score 1):

When you are searching in Nautilus (versions 2 and above) a small "Searching..." dialog will be shown near the bottom of the Nautilus window while the search is in progress. When the search is complete, the dialog will disappear. You will know that the search is complete.

[image: In this picture, Nautilus is not done searching, so the dialog is still shown.]

Comment: Yes, but when the first file was find that small "Searching..." dialog disappear even if the search process continue.

Comment: In that case it might be a good idea to compile a bug report. You can do so [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/).